# remove & take out from the null entry

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project & branches model in Laravel, each project has many branches.
this function is work very well but it saved Empty records from $request->branches

```
$data = $request->except('branches');
$branches = collect($request->branches)->transform(function($branch) {
    $branch['name'] = $branch['name'];
    return new Branch($branch);

});        

$data = $request->except('branches');
$data['user_id'] = $user->id;
$project = Project::create($data);
$project->branches()->saveMany($branches);
return response()->json(['created' => true,]);
```

I want to remove empty record from branches request.
this is the log of array:

$request->branches:

```
 local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

$branches (after collect) :

```
local.INFO: [{"name":null}]
```

Comment: Sounds fine - what's your question about this? Why not simply remove whatever you don't want to save before saving?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function

```
$filteredBranches = $branches->filter();
```

See [Documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter).

Answer (score 0):

I use the reject function

```
->reject(function ($branch) {return empty($branch['name']);})
```